# During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: [ idCat=1libelle=Gamme Azurdescription= ]

Tags: jpa

Iam try to persist two object produits and categorie who is in relationship.
I coud get to persist categorie but not produits : 
I have this kind exception

```
During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: com.backupapi.entity.Categorie[ idCat=1libelle=Gamme Azurdescription= ].
```

here is the class produits

```
public class Produits implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_Prod")
    private Integer idProd;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "libelle")
    private String libelle;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "prixUnitaire")
    private float prixUnitaire;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "datePeremption")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date datePeremption;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_Cat", referencedColumnName = "id_Cat")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Categorie idCat;


public String toString() {
        return " com.backupapi.entity.Produits[idProd=" + idProd + " libelle="+libelle+" prix Unitaire="+prixUnitaire+" date Peremption="+datePeremption+"id_cat="+idCat+" ]";
    }
```

here is the class categorie

```
public class Categorie implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_Cat")
    private Integer idCat;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "libelle")
    private String libelle;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idCat")
    private List<Produits> produitsList;
 @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.backupapi.entity.Categorie[ idCat=" + idCat +"libelle="+libelle+"description="+description+" ]";
    }
```

here is the Jpa method for persist 
Iam persist a element of list

```
  public void createCategorie(List<Object> objectList) {
        //boolean bool=false;
        for(Object listElement:objectList){
        try {
            this.em.persist(listElement);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //if (listElement==null){bool= false;}else{bool=  true;}
        }
```

Is there the main method

```
  for (Class entiClass : generic.allClassname()) {
                List<Object> Objectlist = new ArrayList<>();
                JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(entiClass);
                Objectlist = entityListfromxml(context, entiClass, "test.xml");
                System.out.println(Objectlist.toString());
                genericRestore.createCategorie(Objectlist);
               // System.out.println(Objectlist.toString());
                //System.out.println(test);
            }
```

By executing it is what sends me the method tostring

```
[com.backupapi.entity.Categorie[ idCat=1libelle=Gamme Azurdescription= ], com.backupapi.entity.Categorie[ idCat=2libelle=Gamme Propredescription= ], com.backupapi.entity.Categorie[ idCat=3libelle=Gamme alimentairedescription=null ]]
[ com.backupapi.entity.Produits[idProd=1 libelle=HP-PC prix Unitaire=200000.0 date Peremption=Tue Jul 19 00:00:00 UTC 2016id_cat=com.backupapi.entity.Categorie[ idCat=1libelle=Gamme Azurdescription= ] ],  com.backupapi.entity.Produits[idProd=2 libelle=Saucisse prix Unitaire=500.0 date Peremption=Thu Jul 21 00:00:00 UTC 2016id_cat=com.backupapi.entity.Categorie[ idCat=3libelle=Gamme alimentairedescription=null ] ],  com.backupapi.entity.Produits[idProd=3 libelle=Gateau prix Unitaire=25.0 date Peremption=Tue Jul 12 00:00:00 UTC 2016id_cat=com.backupapi.entity.Categorie[ idCat=3libelle=Gamme alimentairedescription=null ] ]]
```

Iam use metadata to have all classe in project .

So, how to do to persist produits